# File System function: Is it possible to use overwrite mode and append mode in same time?

Tags: php

In a file text, i need to overwrite some lines. It's not a problem with fopen "r+" mode and fseek function ( calculate numbers characters of the line and place pointer in accordingly for rewriting).

When I finish to write and add more text on the line, I doesn't want my new line overwrite the beginning of the next line. ( depend of the numbers of characters added, of course ).

Is it possible ?

Comment: Recreate file or Pad lines with whitespace (you have to recreate your file) to increase their capacity. But it better to use database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want to overwrite a single line, essentially? This is only possible if your newly-written line has the exact same number of bytes. Files are sequences of bytes. You can replace some in between, but lines are an interpretation atop of that, so overwriting bytes at one location might just as well overwrite a new line sequence as well if what you're writing is longer than the previous line.

The usual way to deal with that is to seek to the point where you want to replace the line, read the rest of the file into a buffer, write your new line, write the buffer.

Comment: Ok, when i overwrite my line, if isn't the same number of bytes, it's impossible except if i use a buffer solution for rewrite the rest of the text. Thx sir !